# Wkhtmltopdf Gives An uncaught Exception

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to wkhtmltopdf for download my data to pdf getting an errors below.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered    
Type: Exception
Message: System error
Loading pages (1/6)

[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[=======>                                                    ] 12%
Warning: SSL error ignored                                        
[========>                                                   ] 14%
[=========>                                                  ] 16%
[==========>                                                 ] 18%
[============>                                               ] 20%
[=============>                                              ] 23%
[===============>                                            ] 25%
[================>                                           ] 27%
[=================>                                          ] 29%
[==================>                                         ] 31%
[===================>                                        ] 33%
[=====================>                                      ] 35%
[======================>                                     ] 38%
[========================>                                   ] 40%
[=========================>                                  ] 43%
[===========================>                                ] 45%
[============================>                               ] 47%
[=============================>                              ] 49%
[=====================================>                      ] 63%
[==========================================>                 ] 70%
[=============================================>              ] 76%
[=================================================>          ] 83%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[==============================>                             ] Page 1 of 2
[============================================================] Page 2 of 2
Done                                                                      

Filename: application/libraries/Wkhtmltopdf.php
Line Number: 866
Backtrace:

File: /var/www/admin/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Here's the line from my PHP codeigniter file that's sending the error in case that helps:

```
$html = $this->load->view('report/view_course_summary_pdf', $data, true);    
$pdfFilePath = "Course_Summary_Report.pdf";
$options['path'] = $myPath;
$options['orientation'] = 'Landscape';
$options['commandOptions'] = 
            array(
                'useExec' => true, // Can help if generation fails without a useful error message
                'procEnv' => array(
                    // Check the output of 'locale' on your system to find supported languages
                    'LANG' => "'" . $this->session->userdata('lang_code') . "_US.utf-8" . "'",
                )
            );
            $this->load->library('wkhtmltopdf', $options);
            $this->wkhtmltopdf->setTitle($this->common_lang->get_lang_token('course_summary_report'));
            $this->wkhtmltopdf->setOptions(['ignoreWarnings' => true]);
            $this->wkhtmltopdf->setHtml($html); // $html can be a url or html content.
            $this->wkhtmltopdf->output(Wkhtmltopdf::MODE_DOWNLOAD, $pdfFilePath);
```

A bunch of people have talked about similar issues that are related to using WKPDF with an SSL, but I don't think that's causing my problems since it says the SSL error was ignored... Any help would be really appreciated. Whenever I try doing it, there my HTML is download but it corrupted format using above Codeginter code.

Comment: try adding setting `'ignoreWarnings' => true,` to commandOptions like this

 `$options['commandOptions'] = 
            array(
                'ignoreWarnings' => true,
                'useExec' => true, // Can help if generation fails without a useful error message
                'procEnv' => array(
                    // Check the output of 'locale' on your system to find supported languages
                    'LANG' => "'" . $this->session->userdata('lang_code') . "_US.utf-8" . "'",
                )
            );`